# Generating function of the Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, generating-functions, contour-integration, residue-calculus

The Laguerre Polynomials have the following integral representations $$L_{n}^{\alpha} (x) = x^{-\alpha} e^x \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_c \frac{e^{-z} z^{n+\alpha}}{(z-x)^{n+1}} dz$$ where $c$ is an anticlockwise contour around $z=x$.  Use these to show that the generating function defined as $$F^{\alpha} (t,x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t^n L_n^{\alpha} (x),$$ is given by $$F^{\alpha}(t,x) = \frac{1}{(1-t)^{\alpha+1}}e^{-\frac{xt}{1-t}}$$ Assume that for small enough $t$, the order of integration and summation may be swapped and any resulting poles lie within the contour.

Attempt: Swapping the order of integration as hinted at gives $$F = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_c  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{zt}{(z-x)}\right)^n \frac{e^{-z+x} z^{\alpha} x^{-\alpha}}{(z-x)}dz$$ Now for $t$ small, I can write the sum as a geometric series (and in fact there is a hint in the question that a geometric series should be obtained), so I can write the sum of the series as $1/(1- (zt/(z-x))$. Now inputting, rearranging gives the formula $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} e^x x^{-\alpha} \oint \frac{e^{-z} z^{\alpha}}{z(1-t)-x}dz$$ Per the question, we assume the pole $z = x/(1-t)$ lies within the contour and evaluating by residue theorem gives the result $$\frac{1}{(1-t)^{\alpha}}e^{\frac{-xt}{(1-t)}}$$ so I am off by a factor of $1/(1-t)$ just. I can't see it, any help would be great. I hope it is something obvious and my method is fine.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, good job on this computation.  Everything looks correct, except for your calculation of the residue.  Note that
\begin{align*}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z(1-t) - x}, \frac{x}{1-t}\right) = \lim_{z \to \frac{x}{1-t}} \left(z - \frac{x}{1-t}\right) \frac{1}{z(1-t) - x} = \frac{1}{1-t}
\end{align*}
which accounts for the missing factor of $\frac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me.  From this we can determine that $$L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_{C'} \frac{1}{(1-t)^{\alpha+1} t^{n+1}} e^{-\frac{xt}{1-x}} dt$$ Now set $\alpha = n$ and I want to find the leading asymyptotic behaviour for large $n$. For this the saddle point method could be applied. Are you familiar with this? I thought about reexpressing the terms dependent on $n$ in the integrand there by exponentials so I could use the method but my choice results in a vanishing second derivative of the function multiplying $n$. Should I update the main post for this? Thanks again!

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the saddle point method.  You might want to post this as a new question since the topic (asymptotics) is different than your computation.

Comment: sure, no problem and thanks for your help! +1,accepted